# Drawing vertical and slanted arrows in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have a few questions regarding my MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\tikzstyle{cloud} = [ellipse, draw, fill=red!20, text centered, minimum width=50pt, minimum height=25pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[cloud] (mycloud) at (6.9,7) {Cloud};
\node[block]  (c1) at (5,5) {Consumer L1};
\node[block]  (c2) at (9,5) {Consumer L2};
\node[block]  (f1) at (6.9,3) {Feeder F1};

\path [line] (f1) - (mycloud); % fails
\path [line] (c1) |- (f1);
\path [line] (f1) -| (c2);
\path [line] (c1) |- (f1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

1. How do I draw a vertical arrow from the top ellipse (Cloud) to the bottom rectangle (Feeder F1)?
2. Draw arrows from the center of the top edges of each of **L1** and **L2** to the center of the ellipse (i.e the bottom-most point of the ellipse)?
3. Ensure that each of **L1** and **L2** is equidistant from the ellipse without manually specifying the co-ordinates?

[image: Output]

EDIT:
I was able to solve **1)** with `\draw[->,-latex] (mycloud) -- (f1);` but would like answers for **2)** and **3)**

[image: After Edits]

Comment: Please add with an external graphic program the arrows you want.

Comment: @linuxfan please see if the answer below satisfies question 2

Comment: @linuxfan the `positioning` tikzlibrary helps with equal distancing without calculations as you can see in the edited answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more, "fancy" variation (for exercises), however with use of the recent syntax for defining styles of image elements:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shadows, shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 4mm and 2mm,
mycloud/.style = {cloud, cloud puffs=9.4, aspect=2,
                  draw, draw, fill=red!20, drop shadow,
                  minimum width=50pt, align=center},
  block/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20, 
                  minimum height=2em, text width=5em, align=center},
    arr/.style = {semithick, -Stealth},
every edge/.style = {arr, draw}
                    ]
% nodes
\node[mycloud] (c0)  {Cloud};
\node[block, below  left=of c0] (c1) {Consumer L1};
\node[block, below right=of c0] (c2) {Consumer L1};
\node[block, below=of c0 |- c1.south] (f1) {Feeder F1};
% conections
\path   (c1) edge (c0)
        (c2) edge (c0)
        (c0) edge (f1);
\draw[arr]  (c1) |- (f1);
\draw[arr]  (f1) -| (c2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Zarko this solution is much nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}

\tikzstyle{cloud} = [ellipse, draw, fill=red!20, text centered, minimum width=50pt, 
minimum height=25pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, 
 rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[cloud] (mycloud) at (6.9,7) {Cloud};
\node[block]  (c1) at (5,5) {Consumer L1};
\node[block]  (c2) at (9,5) {Consumer L2};
\node[block]  (f1) at (6.9,3) {Feeder F1};

%\path [line] (f1) - (mycloud); % fails
\path [line] (c1) |- (f1);
\path [line] (f1) -| (c2);
\path [line] (c1) |- (f1);

\draw[line]($(mycloud.south)+(0,-1em)$)-|(c2.north);
\draw[line]($(mycloud.south)+(0,-1em)$)-|(c1.north);
\draw[]($(mycloud.south)+(0,-1em)$)--(mycloud.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT up pointing arrows from L1 and L2**

The `positioning` with the help of tiklibrary in preamble helps for equal distancing rather than manual calculation as desired in question 3

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc,positioning}

\tikzstyle{cloud} = [ellipse, draw, fill=red!20, text centered, minimum 
width=50pt, minimum height=25pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text 
centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[cloud] (mycloud)  {Cloud};
\node[block, below left=of mycloud]  (c1) {Consumer L1};
\node[block, below right=of mycloud]  (c2) {Consumer L1};
\node[block, below=2cm of mycloud]  (f1)  {Feeder F1};

%\path [line] (f1) - (mycloud); % fails
\path [line] (c1) |- (f1);
\path [line] (f1) -| (c2);
\path [line] (c1) |- (f1);

\draw[line](c2.north)to(mycloud.south east);
\draw[line](c1.north)to(mycloud.south west);
\draw[line](mycloud.south)to(f1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```